# How can i improve my python code regarding while loops

Tags: python-2.7

Could someone look at my code and tell me some ways of which i could make my code more efficient or shorter. My program basically generates 2 numbers between 1 and 6 and takes their sum. If the sum is equal to either 3,7,11 the program say "you won". If the sum is a odd number, it say "you lose". And if the sum is an even number, it says "draw". Lastly it displays the number of games won and the percentage of games won. How can i make the part where it asks the user if they want to play again more efficient.(still new to python). Thanks

```
import random
random.seed(1234)

GamesPlayed=0
Won=0

print "DICE ROLLING GAME"
print

while True:
    #generates 2 numbers from 1 to 6
    num1=random.randint(1,6) 
    num2=random.randint(1,6) 

    total=num1+num2

    #This part checks to see if that total is equal to 3,7, or 11. it will say you win
    if total==3 or total==7 or total==11:
        print "I just rolled %d and %d." % (num1, num2)
        GamesPlayed+=1
        Won+=1
        print "You Win!"
        print 
        #next part ask user if they would like to play again
        user=raw_input("Would you like to try again (y/n): ") 
        if user=="N" or user=="n":
            break
        elif user=="Y" or user=="y":
            continue
    #next part checks to see if the two random numbers are odd numbers, if so, it displays "you lose"    
    elif total % 2==1:
        print "I just rolled %d and %d." % (num1, num2)
        print "Lose!"
        GamesPlayed+=1
        print 
        #ask if the user would want to go again
        user=raw_input("Would you like to try again (y/n): ") 
        if user=="N" or user=="n":
            break
        elif user=="Y" or user=="y":
            continue
    #If the total is an even number, it say "draw"
    elif total % 2==0:
        print "I just rolled %d and %d." % (num1, num2)
        print "Draw"
        GamesPlayed+=1
        print 
        user=raw_input("Would you like to try again (y/n): ") 
        if user=="N" or user=="n":
            break
        elif user=="Y" or user=="y":
            continue       

#displays how many games the user won out of the number of games they played, also displays the percentage of the amount they won
print "You won %d out of %d games, or %.0f%%." % (Won, GamesPlayed, (float(Won) / GamesPlayed) * 100)
```

Comment: first add spaces around `=`, `==`,  `+=` to make it more readable Use `lower_case` names for variables. We use `CamelCase` names for classes. Find `PEP8` document about Python code formatting.

Comment: you can do `if total in (3, 7, 11)` and use `user = user.lower()`  so you will no need `user == "N"`, etc.

Comment: in you code `elif ... continue` is useless. It will work the same way without all `continue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You repeat the same code in `if/elif` but you could do it once.

You can use `lower()` and then you don't have to compare with upper `N`. You can use `strip()` because sometimes people can put space(s) in answer and not see this.

You can use `if total in (3, 7, 11):`.
Similar you can use ie. `if user in ('n', 'no', 'quit'):`

See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

- use `lower_case` names for variables
- add spaces around `=`, `==`, `+=`, etc
- add space after comma

Code:

```
import random
import time

random.seed(time.time())

games_played = 0
won = 0

print "DICE ROLLING GAME"
print

while True:
    games_played += 1

    num1 = random.randint(1, 6) 
    num2 = random.randint(1, 6) 

    total = num1 + num2

    print "I just rolled %d and %d (total: %d)." % (num1, num2, total)

    if total in (3, 7, 11):
        print "You Win!"
        won += 1
    elif total % 2 == 1:
        print "Lose!"
    #elif total % 2 == 0:
    else:
        print "Draw"

    print 

    answer = raw_input("Would you like to try again (y/n): ")
    answer = answer.strip().lower()

    if answer == "n":
        break

    print

print "You won %d out of %d games, or %.0f%%." % (won, games_played, (float(won) / games_played) * 100)
```

And use some random value as seed (ie. current timestamp) because `seed(1234)` gives always the same results.